# SourceTree : download source files for a particular commit

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree version-4.1.3.
I want to download source files changed in a particular commit.
Upon selecting commit from the history and chose Archive option, it download complete source of the branch up-to that selected commit.

What is the best way to do that using SourceTree?

Comment: I think it is not possible with bitbucket/sourcetree anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try `git cherry-pick`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Follow the steps:

1. Make sure you are on the branch you want to apply the commit to:

`git switch master`

2. Execute the following:

`git cherry-pick [commit-hash]`